# How add / edit / remove many to many relationships in google app maker using tables?

Tags: many-to-many, google-app-maker

I have the following scenario centered around the relationship between 2 models: Assets and Activities.

Many Assets can be INPUT of Many Activities at parallel times.

Having that in mind - I want to create UI, which allows me to:

- from the perspective of Activity:
- add Assets as related to the Activity into a table by selecting them from an existing table of Assets showing all created Assets.
- Be able to remove the relationship by clicking a button (which would not delete the whole record in the table).

Please help. Thank you in advance!

I tried binding custom code to an onClick event to a button, which is on the same row as the Asset record I would like to un-relate from an associated activity:

`var index = widget.root.datasource.item.Assets.indexOf(widget.datasource.item);
widget.root.datasource.item.Assets.splice(index, 1);`

This returns:

Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined
at Strategy_TableView.Panel1.Table2.Table2Body.Table2Row.Button5.onClick:1:51

I also have yet to try to find a way to add existing Assets to the related to Activities table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggested code edits to get this working correctly would be:

```
var datasourcerelation = widget.root.datasource.relations.Services;
var index = datasourcerelation.items.indexOf(widget.datasource.item);
datasourcerelation.items.splice(index, 1);
```

For whatever reason referencing `datasource.item.Services` in relation to JS array functions does not give you the result needed. I am not sure why this is, but you have to use `datasource.relations.Services` instead.

In regards to adding to the relation use:

```
var datasourcerelation = widget.root.datasource.item.Services;
datasourcerelation.push(widget.datasource.item);
```

Note that in the case of adding a relation `datasource.item.Services` works fine. I am not sure why this is different.

Comment: I am most thankful for your response Markus! 

I have a problem though, when I bind to a button:
`var datasourcerelation = widget.root.datasource.relations.Services;
var index = datasourcerelation.items.indexOf(widget.datasource.item);
datasourcerelation.items.splice(index, 1);`


I receive: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of null
at Strategy_TableView.Panel1.Table2.Table2Body.Table2Row.Button5.onClick:2:38

I am sure I am not doing something properly. I'm adding more details in the next comment.

Comment: Details:

I have 2 tables. Table 1 holds Activities and has Activities as datasource.

Table 2 is holds Assets and has datasource Activities: Assets (relation)

In table on a row with a record of Asset I've added a button with the bound onClick function:

`var index = widget.root.datasource.item.Asset.indexOf(widget.datasource.item); widget.root.datasource.item.Asset.splice(index, 1);`

I've also tried your variant, but on click it in both cases returns: 
Cannot read property 'indexOf' of null at Strategy_TableView.Panel1.Table2.Table2Body.Table2Row.Button5.onClick:2:38

Comment: In regards to using:

`var datasourcerelation = widget.root.datasource.item.a3_Assets;
datasourcerelation.push(widget.datasource.item);`

I receive: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
at Strategy_TableView.Panel4.Table4Panel.Table4.Table4Body.Table4Row.Button6.onClick:2:20

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is that your widget.root does not have a datasource assigned to it or it does not have Activities as a datasource. Using widget.root will point to your top level page element so make sure it does in fact have Activities as a datasource. Alternatively just replace widget.root.datasource with app.datasources.Activities. There may still be other problems but I’d start with that.

Comment: @Veso Yanchev also I just noticed that your splice function might be assigned to the wrong table. And for adding Assets to your Activities you will need a third table pointing to Assets only if you use push to add relations or you can use a multiselect with options set to ‘@datasources.Assets.items’.

Comment: I am most thankful for your suggestions. I will try to implement them.

Comment: I noticed I've missed to send feedback in this regard. Markus was right about the proper relation between datasources and addressing the top level page element / or children. I was not addressing the elements in the correct way, referring to the code edit suggestions above.